# Filtering, Slicing, Sorting in Javascript through Angular Factory

Tags: javascript, arrays, angularjs, object, filter

I'm trying to create a list of data items that have first been filtered by value, then sorted by descending value, then sliced to only show the top 5 items. I'm using an Angular factory to return these values to my controller, so that I can display the values in the DOM.

I've been successful in sorting and slicing the data, but I'm running into problems when I run **`dataHandler.filter`**. I get the error: `'Cannot read property 'slice' of undefined'`.

Here is my controller where I try to return a new list after running each of these functions:

**Controller**

```
getData().then(function(data) {

    function updateChart() {
        // get match value
        var filterValue = inputService.primaryInputs[0]["value"];

        // plug match value into filter ** should return only data items with matches
        var filtered = dataHandler.filter(data, "Description", filterValue);

        // sort by descending value "percent"
        var sorted = dataHandler.sort.descending(filtered, "Percent");

        // return top 5 results
        var sliced = dataHandler.slice(sorted, 5);
        $scope.barData = sliced;
    }
    updateChart();

});
```

I know that `dataHandler.sort.descending` and `dataHandler.slice` or working correctly, because I can use `data` as an argument in `dataHandler.sort.descending` and the list is returned perfectly. However, when I try to plug use `filtered`, I get `'Cannot read property 'slice' of undefined'`.

**Factory**

```
app.factory('dataHandler', function ($rootScope) {
    return {
        filter: function(data, dataProp, input) {
            data.filter(function(value, index, array) {
                console.log(value[dataProp] == input);
                return value[dataProp] == input;
            });
        },
        sort: {
            ascending: function (data, sortCriteria) {
                if (data) {
                    data.sort(function (a, b) {
                        return a[sortCriteria] - b[sortCriteria];
                    });
                };
                return data;
            },
            descending: function (data, sortCriteria) {
                if (data) {
                    data.sort(function (a, b) {
                        return b[sortCriteria] - a[sortCriteria];
                    });
                };
                return data;
            }
        },
        slice: function (data, howMany) {
            if (howMany) {
                return data.slice(0, howMany);
            } else {
                return data;
            }
        }
    };
```

Again - I want to use `dataHandler.filter` to return a new list with only the items whose `Description` values match the `filterValue`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason it doesn't work is because you aren't returning anything in your `dataHandler.filter` function.

It should be:

```
filter: function(data, dataProp, input) {
  return data.filter(function(value, index, array) {
    console.log(value[dataProp] == input);
    return value[dataProp] == input;
  });
}
```

Remember that [`Array.prototype.filter`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) does not work in place, like [`Array.prototype.reverse`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reverse).

---

Even though this will work, I would suggest that you don't actually need a factory for these tasks. Filtering, slicing and sorting are very general purpose tasks and there is no need to wrap around the native implementation (unless you are polyfilling).

I would rewrite the entire factory as a service of reusable transform functions that can be used in a series of chained operations.

```
.service('Transform', function() {
  // we will pass this to filter
  this.propEquals = function(property, value) {
    return function(data) {
      return data[property] === value;
    };
  };

  // we'll pass this to sort
  this.sort = function(criteria, ascending) {
    return function(a, b) {
      return ascending?
        a[criteria] - b[criteria] : b[criteria] - a[criteria];
    };
  };
})
```

Then your `updateChart` method becomes.

```
function updateChart() {
  var filterValue = inputService.primaryInputs[0]["value"];

  $scope.barData = data
    .filter(Transform.propEquals("description", filterValue))
    .sort(Transform.sort("Percent", false))
    .slice(0, 5);
}
```